# Updating mongo collection using mongoose findOneAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following schema designed and insert is working fine

```
  {
    "uid" : "541a5edaef7b20086c2c9ea0",
    "_id" : ObjectId("541a6bca735a20060c593813"),
    "exams" : [ 
        {
            "start_time" : "2014-09-18T05:21:14.219Z",
            "status" : "passed",
            "chapter_id" : ObjectId("54194290022f6d830f255f2e")
        }, 
        {
            "start_time" : "2014-09-18T05:26:14.219Z",
            "status" : "attending",
            "chapter_id" : ObjectId("54194290022f6d830f255f2f")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

How can i update the second element in **exams** key, so that the result will be

```
{
        "uid" : "541a5edaef7b20086c2c9ea0",
        "_id" : ObjectId("541a6bca735a20060c593813"),
        "exams" : [ 
            {
                "start_time" : "2014-09-18T05:21:14.219Z",
                "status" : "passed",
                "chapter_id" : ObjectId("54194290022f6d830f255f2e")
            }, 
            {
                "start_time" : "2014-09-18T05:26:14.219Z",
                **"status" : "failed",**
                "chapter_id" : ObjectId("54194290022f6d830f255f2f")
            }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
    }
```

My model is defined as follows

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var examSchema = new Schema({
  uid: String,
  exams: []
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Exam',examSchema);
```

I tried this query to update ,but gets the error like

```
Exam.findOneAndUpdate({ _id:uid, exams.chapter_id: chapterId }, { exams.status:'passed})
                                          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a way. 
Since my subdoc filed "chapter_id" is a MongoDB ObjectID we need to pass it something like

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
Exam.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id, exams:{$elemMatch:{'chapter_id': new ObjectId(chapterId)}}}, { 'exams.$.status' : passStatus }, function(err,doc) {
    res.send(doc);
  });
```

Thanks [John Greenall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1590306/john-greenall)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to enclose exams.chapter_id in quotes:

```
"exams.chapter_id"
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes the error disappear, but no change in db.

Comment: @BluezTechz have you read about the positional operator? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/ The example at the end of that page is essentially identical to your use case